# How to use platex on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, uplatex, platex

How can one process a document using `\documentclass{jarticle}` on Overleaf? This class requires pLaTeX, which is not available from the web interface.

Comment: Did you read http://doratex.hatenablog.jp/entry/20150903/1441252705 ?

Comment: @Marijin I hope I could understand  Japanese. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes—by adding a [custom `latexmkrc` file](https://www.overleaf.com/help/202-does-overleaf-support-ptex) in your project, containing the following lines:

```
$latex = 'platex';
$bibtex = 'pbibtex';
```

You will also need to set the LaTeX engine of your project to `LaTeX+dvipdf`; this setting can be found by clicking on the gear icon on the upper right of the Overleaf editor.

Here's an [example project](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/platex-shi-yan/jzxphyvjdzkv). (After opening the template, you may need to click on the `PROJECT` button at the top, to toggle the file list open, to view the `latexmkrc` file.)

If you just need to typeset a Japanese article and are not restricted to the (u)pTeX classes, you may want to take a look at the `ltjarticle` class instead, from the [`luatexja` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/luatexja). It uses LuaLaTeX, and is more robust and up-to-date.